# Loop nesting and I'm getting a blank page (php)

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

Here's what I got-

```
    $awards_sql_1 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM categories WHERE section_id = 1') or die(mysql_error());
    $awards_rows_1 = mysql_num_rows($awards_sql_1);
    $awards_sql_2 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM categories WHERE section_id = 2') or die(mysql_error());
    $awards_sql_3 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM categories WHERE section_id = 3') or die(mysql_error());
    $awards_sql_4 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM categories WHERE section_id = 4') or die(mysql_error());

    $i = 0;
    $records = mysql_num_rows($sections_query);
    while($row_sections = mysql_fetch_array($sections_query)) {
        echo "<h3>" . $row_sections['section_name'] . "</h3>";
        echo "<ul>";
        //while($categories = mysql_fetch_array($awards_sql_1)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $awards_rows_1; $i++) {
            echo "<li><strong>$categories['category_name']</strong>";

        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
```

For some reason, if I comment out the for() nested in the while(), the page will load fine and I'll see all of my h3's, however, whenever I try to nest a for() or while() inside the original while(), the page just goes blank on reload.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing a </li> tag. I don't know that that would hang the script, but it's the first thing I noticed.

Comment: yeah, that's not affecting the script.  it's hanging off of there because once i figure this out, i'll nest another loop in there and then close it off.  :)

Comment: Additionally, turning on error reporting can be quite helpful and let you know why it dumped 

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.errorfunc.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put braces around array variables embedded in strings, otherwise you get a parse error.

```
 echo "<li><strong>{$categories['category_name']}</strong>";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: thank you, that solved the blank page problem.  didn't know that!

Answer (score 1):

Try with, you'll get the error:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
...
```